# Disp command format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date

I am the struggling with the following command.  In reality, it is to be executed as a SQL statement.  I am printing out the statement below using `disp` command.

```
Datevar = datestr(date,'mm/dd/yyyy') ; % 07/25/2011 

% Required command: execute SQLname @startdate = '7/25/2011'

% My current command:
disp([...
'execute SQLname ' ...
'@startdate = ' ''' Datevar ''' ...
])
```

I have tried many combinations but I am not able to hit this string right: @startdate = '7/25/2011'.  Thanks!

Comment: Awright..this finally works:     
    '@StartDate = ''' datestr(START_DATE) ''''
However, I have to use datestr func here.  Any comments/suggestions plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Misplaced quote, at least in the example code you posted. That third line of the disp call is concatenating two separate strings, and the second one contains a literal "Datevar". You want this, which will concatenate the contents of the variable named Datevar.

```
sql = [...
'execute SQLname ' ...
'@startdate = ''' Datevar '''' ...
];
disp(sql);
```

IMHO, short queries like these are more readable if you construct them with sprintf, because you don't have to differentiate between internal quotes and delimiting quotes.

```
sql = sprintf('execute SQLname @startdate = ''%s''', Datevar);
```

If you include an example of the exact output you are getting, it's easier to diagnose problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are do not want the leading zeroes provided by `datestr`. There are no date specifiers for returning non-padded day and month values. You can create the string you want by using [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html) and [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) like this:

```
>> date = datevec('2011/07/25');
>> sprintf('execute SQLname @startdate = ''%u/%u/%u''', date([2 3 1]))

ans =

execute SQLname @startdate = '7/25/2011'
```

Comment: Thanks B3. The leading 0 is not a problem! SQL can ignore it.  disp/sprintf issue is also not important as this command would ultimately run inside a cursor connection: exec .... I am using disp just to debug my statement.